# Does $f(x)=x(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$ decrease with $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

Does $f(x)=x(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$  decrease with $x\in[0,\infty)$?

I calculated the derivative of $f$, which is $f^{'}(x)=2^{\frac{1}{x}}(1-\frac{1}{x}\ln2)-1$. But how to prove that $f^{'}(x)<0$ when $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Does anyone give me a hint for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @crskhr That doesn't quite work, you have a product of an increasing function and a decreasing function, and somehow you want to argue that the decreasing function "wins". To do this you cannot simply freeze the factor of $x$ as if it were a fixed value, you should be multiplying the left side by $x$ and the right side by $y$...but now you multiplied the right side by *more* than the left side, which could spoil the inequality.

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Comment: @Ian Haha! Sorry, My bad! What you said is correct. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see it is to switch variables to $u=1/x$, now $\frac{2^u-1}{u}$ is an increasing function of $u$ because of convexity of $2^x$ (because it is the slope of the secant line of $2^x$ between $x=0$ and $x=u$). This gives you that $x(2^{1/x}-1)$ is a decreasing function of $x$ at least for $x>0$ where the change of variable made sense.

Dealing with $x=0$ requires you to tell us what $f(0)$ is; if it is understood as $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$, then that's $+\infty$, which achieves what you want.

Comment: Pretty slick! +1